# Mesh resizing on bone rotation in pose mode?

Tags: rigging, bones

How can I prevent the mesh from shrinking when the bone is rotated?

In the second image the shield is shrinking in size as I rotate the bone further. I want to the dimensions of the shield, similar to the third image where no shrinking is occurring.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the shield vertices in *Edit* mode, go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups* and click on *Remove from All Groups*:

[image]

Keep the vertices selected, select the vertex group the shield is supposed to be part of and click on the *Assign* button:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It is because that particular mesh is on multiple vertex groups.

Comment: Yes that's it, therefore it's deformed by other bones